# knitr, pandoc: How to prepare a journal TeX submission ZIP file from an Rmd file?

Tags: makefile, latex, knitr, pandoc

The combination of knitr, pandoc and R Studio is great for writing academic papers in `.Rmd` format, but now that my article has been accepted, I'm stumped on how to prepare a `.zip` file containing all the LaTeX sources required for the journal.   The instructions I was given are:

```
 INSTRUCTIONS FOR AUTHORS
 WE ASK THAT YOU UPLOAD YOUR SOURCE FILES AT THIS TIME.
 Please upload the following:
 • A PDF of your final paper
 • The TeX or Word file containing your final paper
 • All figure files as separate files
 • Any additional files needed to compile your article. For example, .bbl and .bib files if you used BiBTeX (and we hope you did!), and any special macros
 • Any files to be posted as online supplementary material
```

When I write directly in LaTeX, I have a workflow for this, that essentially creates a `Makefile` to create `article.zip` from `article.{tex,aux,log}` and all other dependencies when I type `make zip` in the article directory.

- It uses a perl script, `texdepend` https://ctan.org/pkg/texdepend?lang=en, to find all dependencies (figures, style files, ...) from `article.{tex,aux,log}` and writes lines that can be used in the `Makefile`.
- I also use the perl script `aux2bib`, http://ctan.mirror.rafal.ca/biblio/bibtex/utils/bibtools/aux2bib or `bibtool`, http://www.gerd-neugebauer.de/software/TeX/BibTool/en/, to generate a `.bib` file for the article from multiple local `.bib` files, as given in the `.aux` file.

This workflow doesn't work with PDF files generated by `knitr` and `pandoc`.

- Everything is produced in a single PDF file.  I can get the `.tex` file by including `keep_tex: yes` in the YAML header, but there is no `article.aux` or `article.log` produced. Hence, I can't use any standard tools to find the dependencies, particularly the figure files that are used with `\includegraphics{}`.
- Bibliography references are included inline by `pandoc` in the `article.tex` file, but they seem to be formatted in such a way that it would be difficult for the journal to produce the article in their particular format. It doesn't use `\bibitem`, but rather just formats the references directly, e.g.,

> \hypertarget{ref-Van_Aelst:2011}{}  Aelst, S. V., \& Willems, G.
>   (2011). Robust and efficient one-way MANOVA  tests. \emph{Journal of
>   the American Statistical Association},  \emph{106}(494), 706--718. 
>   \url{http://doi.org/10.1198/jasa.2011.tm09748}

**Edit**
I should add that the reason I need to use `aux2bib` or `bibtool` is that my references are pulled in from various `.bib` files:

```
bibliography: 
  - "../localtexmf/bibtex/bib/statistics.bib"
  - "../localtexmf/bibtex/bib/graphics.bib"
  - "../localtexmf/bibtex/bib/Rpackages.bib"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do your production of `article.Rmd` with

```
output: 
  pdf_document:
    citation_package: natbib
    keep_tex: true
bibliography: 
  - "../localtexmf/bibtex/bib/statistics"
  - "../localtexmf/bibtex/bib/graphics"
  - "../localtexmf/bibtex/bib/Rpackages"
```

you should get what you want, with the LaTeX left behind in `article.tex`, and the figures left behind somewhere in subdirectory `article_files`.  You'll just get a line like

```
\bibliography{../localtexmf/bibtex/bib/statistics,../localtexmf/bibtex/bib/graphics,../localtexmf/bibtex/bib/Rpackages}
```

in the `article.tex` file; you should be able to produce your own aux and bbl files if you need those in the usual LaTeX/BibTeX way.

Edited to add:  instead of

```
    citation_package: natbib
```

you can use

```
    citation_package: biblatex
```

This is a somewhat newer and more flexible set of LaTeX packages for handling references and citations.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25701/bibtex-vs-biber-and-biblatex-vs-natbib for a discussion and comparison.  I wanted to mention this, because if you do choose to use `biblatex`, then you do need to keep the `.bib` extensions on your bibliography files.  And if you switch from `natbib` to `biblatex`, you need to delete the `.bbl` file that was produced by `natbib`, to let `biblatex` produce its own in a different format.

Comment: That would work if all my references were in a single `.bib` file.  See my edit above.

Comment: Just leave off the .bib extensions.  I've edited the answer to show it.